File system problem
Thanks for your answer to my question "Partition" in GParted. I have a file system problem on Ubuntu 18.04.6 ("failure writing sector ... hd0") that prevents both a boot and any mode of re-installation of 18.04.6 (instead of the currently installed 18.04.6, alongside it, and with the whole disk being deleted) with a message about the swap partition (or another partition) like that in The creation of swap space in partition #3 of SCSI1 (0,0,0) (sda) failed and the disk itself being probably OK (by all Dell diagnostics). As I thus understand, it is most reasonable to go to the factory-produced 16.04 OS first. If this works, I would probably be able then to re-install 18.04.6. Only if this does not work, would it be worth deleting the current partitions in the table one by one with GParted and then to try and re-install 18.04.6. If this does not work either, formatting to clear would be the only remaining option before the-installation (if there remains anything
to format then). Is my understanding correct? Thanks very much.

failure writing sector is not a file system problem but indicates a hardware problem. There is also no reason to go back to the factory-installed version 16.04. And nowadays you should neither use 16.04 nor 18.04, both, releases are end of life and not supported anymore. I'd recommend to try to install a supported version, either 20.04 or 22.04 or 24.04. I wouldn't go for 20.04 either because it will reach end of life soon too.

unless there are compelling reasons to the contrary, don't mess with partition tables unlkess you really know what you are doing. Backup any existing important data and install a clean current version of Ubuntu (suggest 22.04 whilst issues with 24.04 continue to be resolved).

All Dell hardware diagnostics are OK. Restoration of 16.04 is needed only to properly format the rest of the disk. Without it, would not the installation of 22.04 have the same problem as that of 18.04? Thanks.

You can always use the installer to format partitions, there is no need to have a working system installed to do that. Boot the install media and try without installing.

This is what I successfully did with 18.04.6. But when I tried to install it, a problem with creating the swap space in partition #3 like that in the cited question from 2017 arose. This is why I may need to format the disk prior to installing the whatever version. The backup of my own files is not a problem.  When I reach initramfs after the error message (failure writing sector...), its exit suggests to correct the file system with a manual fsck, but this seems to be a long and uncertain process, unless there is a way of doing this that do not know. What is the simplest way out? Thanks.
